# Guide or book for ubuntu server

Tags: installation, server, administration

Is there any detailed guide or book for Ubuntu server? 
For installation and administration. Free or commercial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu 11.04 server. Official versions:

- [website](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/index.html)
- [pdf](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/serverguide.pdf)

and

- [Fultus books (PDF)](http://www.linbrary.com/ubuntu/1104/ebooks/Ubuntu_1104_Server_Guide.pdf)

Comment: @Vasillis Found another one (all free. The commercial ones (like on amazon) all seem to be for old versions).

Comment: This guide is very good for start, but later I nead something more detailed. To moving databases, http servers. Move some joomla sites and some more. From fedora 6 to ubuntu server.

Comment: Make different questions for those: you'll get better specific answers for those since you do not need books for those ;-)

Comment: The website and pdf links are not working (404), can you update them, please?